# Can you use "many, many" in this way?

Tags: grammaticality, determiners

Suppose I want to use the phrase "many, many" to compound the "maniness" of the thing I'm describing.

> There are **many, many** people.
>
> The people (of which there are **many, many**)

The first one is standard, but the second one is contended. *Can* it be used in that way?

An example of one that wouldn't be so awkward is:

> There are **lots and lots** of people.
>
> The people (of which there are **lots and lots**)

Each one can be properly used in its singular form, but once repeated, one of them falls apart. Why?

Comment: This is strictly spoken or informal written English. Unless you're writing some kind of serious formal report, business letter, or academic paper that's going to be published in a reputable journal, it shouldn't matter. Who's gonna contend that "many, many" is unreasonable colloquial English? I'd still say "very many people", "myriad people", or "scads of people" instead of "many, many", & certainly anything, even "hordes of people" is better than "lots & lots", which, IMHO, is a sign of limited imagination & perhaps VGS (Valley Girlitosis Syndrome): We **are** talking **usage & style** here.

Comment: But @BillFranke the OP is asking whether the second line can be used at all ("The people (of which there are many, many)"). My answer is no, it can't, but I couldn't tell you why. Good question.

Comment: @JAM: Sure the second line can be used in **colloquial** English. Why not? You say "no" probably for the same reason I'd say "Change it" if I were asked to edit it: I don't like the style. But there's nothing ungrammatical or unnatural about it in spoken or informal written English. Maybe it's awkward because it crosses registers: "_which_ there were _many, many of_" is consistent, but "**of which** there were _many, many_" is inconsistent. ..."**of which** there were **many**" seems consistent to me. One of my American friends says "tiny small towns" and "little small towns" all the time! :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One issue is that you are using *many, many* to compound the number. It doesn't do that: it simply emphasises *many*. Where an adjective is simply repeated for emphasis, you can't repeat it in the style of your second sentence.

> My love is like a red, red rose
>   *My love is like a rose which is red, red.

However, it **can** work if you need it for emphasis in the second form:

> My love is like a rose which is red, **red!**

...but that is quite a particular use.

The phrase *lots and lots* doesn't work in the same way: it's effectively a single unit, just as *red* or *many* is. Because it's a single adjectival phrase and not repeated, you can place it at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Perhaps *lots and lots* works better as a stand alone phrase because *lots* is a noun.

Comment: Those familiar with the vintage BBC radio programmes 'Round the Horne' and 'Beyond our Ken' will perhaps remember Betty Marsden's oft repeated line 'Many times. Many, many times.'

Comment: Perhaps I misused "compound" in the OP; I certainly *meant* something that meant the same as "emphasize".

Comment: @JoeZeng Whatever; the point is that "lots and lots" is a single "unit" just as "many" is, and you can only have one such "unit" at the end of the sentence. Unless you want to shout "red!" contradicting a statement "Ha! Your love is a blue rose."

Answer (score -1):

This is best reserved for the spoken word I think. Use one "many" to convey the meaning, or revise the sentence using a different word, like "multitude," for example.